# Debugging OpenCL kernel in FPGA Arria 10

Tags: debugging, opencl

I am trying to debug a OpenCL kernel for a Arria 10 FPGA board.

First I am compiling for emulation with:

```
$ aoc -march=emulator device/kernel.cl -v -o bin/kernel.aocx
```

And then I can execute the host with the recommended command and works fine:

```
$ env CL_CONTEXT_EMULATOR_DEVICE_ALTERA=1 ./host
```

But when I want to debug I do:

```
$ gdb host
$ (gdb) run
```

which gives me the error:

```
Context callback: Program was compiled for a different board.
       aocx is for board EmulatorDevice whereas device is alaric_v3_prod_hpc
```

I suppose this error is because I am not including the information in "env CL_CONTEXT_EMULATOR_DEVICE_ALTERA=1". How should I execute the host program for debugging? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `gdb` call with env flag, same like you did without debugging:

```
env CL_CONTEXT_EMULATOR_DEVICE_ALTERA=1 gdb ./host
```